# No se puede leer un array de objetos en Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, jsonobject

**Array de objectos:**

```
public comercios = [
  {
    id : 1234,
    cords : {
        lat : 1234,
        lon : 1234
    },
    business : {...} // contiene una gran cantidad de objetos y arrays dentro, 
                        pero en este problema no viene al caso
  },
  {
     ...
  }
];
```

Ese es un array de objetos dinámico que traigo desde otra vista. Ya chequeé con "forIn", "forOf", "for", "forEach", poniendo "comercios[0]",y no he logrado conseguir obtener información alguna de dentro de este.

Es así de literal; Cada for que intento usar, no me devuelve resultado alguno en consola. A su vez, probé colocar "comercios[0]" como mostré más arriba. Ya que también probé cambiando los objetos de dentro del array, por arrays. Y aún así no funciona. Es como si por alguna razón fuera imposible leer los items que componen ese array. Y no es un array complejo. Es algo muy sencillo que no llego a comprender por qué no lo puedo leer con todas esas maneras de leerlo que existen.

por ej:

```
for (const comercio of comercios) {
    console.log(comercio); //no muestra resultado alguno en consola.
}
```

¿Desde dónde se origina el problema?

Gracias

Comment: Pues por lo que parece, tu componente no está recibiendo correctamente los datos. Sin ver el código es complicado ayudarte, te aconsejo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida y entiendas por qué es necesario proveer un [mcve]

Comment: No muestra el resultado porque el for necesita una variable let y no una constante, intenta cambiar comercio a let, e imprime en consola `comercios[comercio]`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar las funciones provistas en el prototype de Array, concretamente el "forEach". A continuación te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var comercios = [
  {
    id : 1234,
    cords : {
        lat : 1234,
        lon : 1234
    },
    business : {} 
  }
];

comercios.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el);
});
```

Cualquier duda que tengas, no dudes en preguntarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he intentado así también, y actúa como si no tuviera datos dentro y por eso no se muestra. Sin embargo, cuando hago console.log a esa variable sin pasarla por ninguna iteración, me muestra todos los datos que tiene correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

No te dejarias els this. no?

```
   for (const comercio of this.comercios) {
        console.log(comercio);
    }
```

Y si no es asi, prueba de hacer console.log(this.comercios.length). Yo creo que la tienes vacia.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Si le hago this.comercios.length me daba 0, pero cuando ponía console.log(this.comercios) me devolvia todo lo que tenia dentro satisfactoriamente. Es como si literalmente estuviera fallando JavaScript y no mi código.

Comment: Y no sera que no es un array? Es raro que el this.comercions.length te de 0